# "the involved discrimination" or "the discrimination involved"?

Tags: idiomatic-language

> 1. In doing so she discriminates against Alan, while keeping from him the
>      **discrimination involved**.
> 2. In doing so she discriminates against Alan, while keeping from him the
>      **involved discrimination**.

Which of the above sentences are more idiomatic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In doing so she discriminates against Alan, while keeping from him the
> discrimination involved.
>
> In doing so she discriminates against Alan, while keeping from him the
> involved discrimination.

Neither of these clearly convey your intended meaning.

Instead, say:

"**In doing so, she discriminates against Alan and hides it from him.**

or

"**This way, she discriminates against Alan without his knowledge.**"

or

"**In doing so, she secretly discriminates against Alan.**"

The last example can also mean she is concealing her discrimination from everyone, and not just from Alan.

Answer (score 0):

Since **involved** can mean "complicated" when used adjectivally, it's a shade better to write

> In doing so she discriminates against Alan, while keeping from him the
>   discrimination involved.

if your meaning is "the discrimination that involves Alan".

Comment: my meaning is the discrimination that is involved in doing so.

Comment: I'm not sure that "the involved discrimination" could mean "the complicated discrimination".

Comment: It could have to do with "red-lining", say, or some discriminatory formula that ranks creditworthiness.

Comment: None of it sounds particularly idiomatic to me, and when spoken you'd almost certainly say something else, but equally it doesn't sound ungrammatical.

Comment: No.  The example here is barely comprehensible.   Do not say or write this.